# codeigniter call controller from controller to build a modular site

Tags: codeigniter

I wish to be able to make a modular codeigniter base in which I can simply load modules into it(not codeigniter modules for clarity)

The setup will be that in the folder controllers there are subfolders with the module names and the same in the views folder.

Now if the controller **application/controllers/showcustomerinfo** is called I want the controller function to call the controllers in **application/controllers/company1/showcustomerinfo** to show and that one does what it needs to do and pushes it output into a view.

So what happens is:

```
base showcustomer info calculates basic info. 
base showcustomer renders view with base header 
base showcustomerinfo fetches information which modules are active 
base showcustomer calls all module controllers also called showcustomer 
company1/showcustomerinfo calculates basic info
company1/showcustomerinfo checks on own modules
company1/showcustomerinfo renders basic info via view
company1/showcustomerinfo stops 
base showcustomerinfo renders base view and footer view 
base showcustomerinfo draws the view.
```

How could I make this happen? How to call a controller from a main controller?

Comment: Why don't you try to use a cms based on codeigniter? maybe somethik like pyrocms.com in this way tou can create the module you need without warry about the structure

Comment: What I need to create is very specific and I'd rather not use models and libraries to call upon but use the controllers to call upon them to do their thing.

Comment: The best you're going to be able to do, I think, is create your own library. You can't, strictly speaking, call another controller from within a controller with CodeIgniter.

Comment: @Brendan that kinda sucks...